# how to change font on entire document? Excel 2008 MacBook

Tags: fonts, macbook

I am using Excel 2008  v. 12.3.6 on a MacBook. Have been sent an Excel file which comes up blank -- can change font from Arial (which I cannot see) to Cambria but only one cell at a time. How do I change the entire document to Cambria?

Answer (score 0):

regarding your query please click on the left top corner of the excel sheet(i.e above row 1 and left to A column). The click will select the whole excel sheet and you can then change the font from arial to Cambria